# Optimizing a MySQL "IN" query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'm trying to optimize a MySQL table for a query of the form:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col3 IN('Val1','Val2','Val3',...)
```

I've added an index to the table:

```
ALTER MyTable ADD INDEX(`COL3`)
```

and verified that it was created, but when I analyze the query using `EXPLAIN` the type is still "ALL" (indicating that all rows are retrieved and searched). What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I've tried `EXPLAIN SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col3 = 'Val1'`. Type is still "ALL". Here are the actual `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` and query:

```
CREATE TABLE RXNCONSO
(
   RXCUI             varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   LAT               varchar (3) DEFAULT 'ENG' NOT NULL,
   TS                varchar (1),
   LUI               varchar(8),
   STT               varchar (3),
   SUI               varchar (8),
   ISPREF            varchar (1),
   RXAUI             varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   SAUI              varchar (50),
   SCUI              varchar (50),
   SDUI              varchar (50),
   SAB               varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   TTY               varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   CODE              varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   STR               varchar (3000) NOT NULL,
   SRL               varchar (10),
   SUPPRESS          varchar (1),
   CVF               varchar(50)
)
;

ALTER TABLE `RXNCONSO` ADD INDEX(`TTY`);

EXPLAIN SELECT RXCUI, STR FROM RXNCONSO
  WHERE TTY IN ('SCD','SBD','GPCK','BPCK','SCDG','SBDG','SCDF','SBDF');

+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | RXNCONSO | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1139206 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Update 2:**

Here's the result of running

```
SELECT TTY, count(1) FROM RXNCONSO
 WHERE TTY IN ('SCD','SBD','GPCK','BPCK','SCDG','SBDG','SCDF','SBDF')   
 GROUP BY TTY WITH ROLLUP;

+------+----------+
| TTY  | count(1) |
+------+----------+
| BPCK |      526 |
| GPCK |      492 |
| SBD  |    21732 |
| SBDF |    14593 |
| SBDG |    21140 |
| SCD  |    36131 |
| SCDF |    14556 |
| SCDG |    16362 |
| NULL |   125532 |
+------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.38 sec)
```

Comment: In your example you added an index on COL3; instead of Col2 being referenced in the where clause

Comment: Please add `show create table MyTable;` and the `EXPLAIN` results. There are multiple possible reasons - one would be mixing unquoted numbers with quoted string (even numeric ones) in the `IN` list.

Comment: An IN list is equivalent to having a bunch of OR parts in the WHERE clause. Even when it's possible to use indexes to find rows satisfying individual OR conditions, db optimizers seldom choose that access path as its usually more expensive than full-scanning the table.

Comment: @zgguy Actually no, `IN` list is usually solved as `range` access, unless the `IN` list covers really big part of the table.

Comment: You can run `SELECT TTY, count(1) FROM RXNCONSO  WHERE TTY IN ('SCD','SBD','GPCK','BPCK','SCDG','SBDG','SCDF','SBDF') GROUP BY TTY WITH ROLLUP;` to see how many rows the query finds, if the total  or the *"Val1"* is going to be too big, the index can not help much (unless you extend it to be covering).

Comment: I would make it a FK and then do a join on RXNCONSO.TTYID = FK.ID and FK.value in (...)   -  and not where -  only a comment and just something to try

Comment: I noticed that the `TTY` is even not among `possible_keys`, thats really weird.. Whats the table engine? Can you try the same with a simplified version of the table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/046b83/1 - seems to work ok for InnoDB table and less rows (but keeping the select at 10% of the table). `show index from RXNCONSO` and if the stats are weird, then `analyze table RXNCONSO` might push it a bit..

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about sqlfiddle. That's quite a tool.

Comment: Looking at EXPLAIN for "TTY =" queries, I'm now getting type = ref. It looks like the answer is that there is a sufficient number of rows in the combination to trigger a full table scan, but that I'd get decent performance if I only selected a few values. Thanks to everybody for pitching in on this. It's really been helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the query optimizer decided a full table scan was best, you might need a new query

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col3 = 'Val1'
UNION
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col3 = 'Val2'
UNION
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM MyTable WHERE Col3 = 'Val3'
UNION ...
```

This should force an indexed lookup per value followed by a merge of the query results

## UPDATE 2015-12-04 15:35 EDT

Based on [jkavalik's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122931/optimizing-a-mysql-in-query/122934?noredirect=1#comment225717_122934), I have a suggestion. Please run this

```
SELECT COUNT(1)/20 INTO @FivePercent FROM RXNCONSO;
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TTY,COUNT(1) ValueCount
    FROM RXNCONSO GROUP BY TTY
) A WHERE ValueCount > @FivePercent
ORDER BY ValueCount DESC;
```

This will show which values will likely contribute to a table scan.

Comment: We don!t know the reason yet.. If the reason was very long IN list and/or the values covering a big part of the table, then all those unions might take more time than a table scan.. And if it was quoting mismatch then it is just not necessary.

Comment: @jkavalik We don't know but this is worth a try

Comment: Empty set (0.63 sec)

Comment: Based on the comment on the values, anyone of those TTY values will trigger a table scan. Please try out other values besides those nine TTYs.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not using index.**
Since "too much" of the table is included by that `WHERE` clause, the index is ignored.  The optimizer decided that a table scan is *probably* faster than bouncing between the index and the data.  Suggest you time it as is, then time it with `FORCE INDEX(col3)` to see if it is faster.

**An optimization.**
A "covering" index is likely to run faster.  (This may require at least 5.6; I am not sure.):  `INDEX(col3, col1, col2)`  Oops, that won't work because `str` is `VARCHAR(3000)` and that is too big for an index.

**Further discussion.**
Explain to me what you will do with 100K rows in a single resultset?  It is rare for an application to do something meaningful with more than a few thousand rows.

Is there no `PRIMARY KEY` on the table?  What `ENGINE` is it using?

Comment: Unfortunately, the query isn't under my control. It's taken from a selection of a terminology called RxNorm, as used by a healthcare information system standard called FHIR.

I think that what I'm going to have to do is "precompute" queries like these (there aren't many of them) and add a column that I can use to retrieve the results efficiently. Not ideal.